# Linear Discriminant Analysis in R - Training and validation samples

Tags: r, validation

I am working with `lda` command to analyze a 2-column, 234 row dataset (x): column X1 contains the predictor variable (metric) and column X2 the independent variable (categorical, 4 categories). I would like to build a linear discriminant model by using 150 observations and then use the other 84 observations for validation. After a random partitioning of data i get x.build and x.validation with 150 and 84 observations, respectively. I run the following

```
fit = lda(x.build$X2~x.build$X1, data=x.build, na.action="na.omit")
```

Then I run predict command like this:

```
pred = predict(fit, newdata=x.validation)
```

From the reading of the commands description I thought that in `pred$class` I would get the classification of validation data according to the model built, but I get the classification of 150 observations instead of the 84 I intended to use as validation data. I don't really know what is happening, can someone please give me an example of how I should be conducting this analysis?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
fit = lda(X2~X1, data=x.build, na.action="na.omit")
pred = predict(fit, newdata=x.validation)
```

If you use this formula `x.build$X2~x.build$X1` when you build the model, predict expects `x.build$X1` column in the validation data. Obviously there isn't one so you get prediction for training data.

Comment: Not to mention that `x.build$X2` is redundant when you have x.build in the data argument.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm wondering why it's wrong to make reference to data columns in the way xbuild$X2... can you tell me something else to learn a bit more? Thank you again :)

Comment: There are two issues: 1) It's unnecessary to tell `R` that `X1` should be found in `x.build` (which is what `x.build$X1` does), you are already doing that by saying `data=x.build`. But more importantly: 2) `predict` is going to look in `newdata` for columns with the name you supplied in `lda`. If you use `x.build$X1` in `lda`, predict will look for `x.validation$x.build$X1`! (And not find it, of course)